# in org-mode, how to change the formatting of timestamps in export to LaTeX?

Tags: org-mode, latex

In org-mode, how can I change the formatting of timestamps exported to LaTeX PDF?

In the generated .tex file, I see that my timestamps are rendered in LaTeX as `\textit`. How can I modify this? I probably want to change it to non-italic monospace font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables are `org-latex-active-timestamp-format` and `org-latex-inactive-timestamp-format`.  Setting them to "\\texttt{%s}" (note the two backslashes) gives you non-italic monospace.